# How to cache each element in List of responses for list of inputs

Tags: java, caching, ehcache

I have a function which calls external system with group of inputs. Then back-end system will give result collective for all inputs.

Later I might need to call that system with single input. I want to avoid that as I have previously got the response for the group of inputs.

I wanted to implement caching with the collective response from other system.

```
public List<Result> process(List<Input> inputs){
// call other system collectively and cache each independent response
// later when I call each input it shall not cal external system because we have cache.

 foreach(Result result: results){
 addtoCache(input, result);

 }
```

}

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "abc")
public Result addToCache(@CacheKey Input input, Result result){
return result;
}

@CacheResult(cacheName = "abc")
public Result getResult(@CacheKey Input input){
//process and send result. It shall not call the external system if the data was obtained previously in process method.
}
```

At later point of time

I will call *getResult* method, will it get the cache cached under *addToCache* method if available.

Can some one help me if this is correct way of implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The annotation is supposed to cache the return object of the method (`result` in the case of `addToCache` method). Both the methods in the code here are modifying the same cache which I believe is unnecessary.

It is better to just have one method, which you want to call eventually, and decorate that with the annotation and you could leave out the other method. The caching will happen whenever you call the `getResult` method, and it will take care of populating the cache, or calling the external system if not cached. Make sure you add the actual implementation in the `getResult` method, i.e the call to the external system inside this method. If the cache contains the object already (the search in the cache will be based on the key that you have defined), it will ensure that the external system doesn't get called.

```
@CacheResult(cacheName = "abc")
public Result getResult(@CacheKey Input input){
//Call the actual service or external system here. 
}
```